# Tareas programadas en Node.js

Tags: nodejs, windows

Me pidieron diseñar un script en nodejs el cual al ejecutarse realiza unas tareas en un servidor windows. El problema es que necesito ejecutar dicha tarea a una hora específica del día por lo que pensé en usar el administrador tareas de windows.

Luego de definir la tarea le doy ejecutar manualmente pero mi script al parecer no arranca. ¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: sube el codigo que tengas amigo, para ayudarte mejor

Comment: ¿quieres tener tu script siempre funcionando (dentro de un proceso nodejs) y a una hora específica invocar una función de tu script? o en cambio quieres que tu script se autoprograme para que cada día a una hora determinada el sistema operativo arranque el script?

Comment: La idea es que el sistema operativo ejecute el script. Normalmente en ambientes de producción no esperas que cuando se inicie el servidor alguien tenga que manualmente ejecutar un script para que esté inicie una rutina cada cierto tiempo... a menos de que sea un servicio claro está

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No necesitas usar ningún programa externo para ejecutar tu script. Puedes usar [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) y poner el código en un callback. Es extrememadamente simple de usar pero debes aprenderte los patrones [cron](http://crontab.org/)

```
* * * * *
```

Significan

```
minutos(0-59)
horas(0-23)
día del mes(0-31)
mes(0-12 o nombres)
día de la semana (0-7, 7 es Domingo, o nombres)
```

Tu código sería algo como

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
// Patrón de cron
// Corre todos los lunes a la 1:00 PM
new CronJob('0 13 * * mon', function() {
  // Código a ejecutar
}, function() {
  // Código a ejecutar cuando la tarea termina. 
  // Puedes pasar null para que no haga nada
}, true);
```

El último argumento indica "inicia inmediatamente".

Puedes ver la lista completa de argumentos en la documentación del [API](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron#api)

Comment: He pensado en usar el cron job dentro de un servicio mediante otro paquete. Esto con el fin de que nadie tenga que ejecutarlo inicialmente. Que opinas?

Comment: @ChristianLopez Por supuesto que puedes hacerlo. Puedes usar [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) o cualquier módulo similar. En el momento que el server inicie programas tus tareas y listo.

Comment: Bueno... la solución fue esa.. use la función cron y halle la forma de ejecutarlo en segundo plano en ambiente windows mediante el paquete forever... aparte usé log entries para monitorear el proceso... muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a una solución fácil. Correr una tarea (que está dentro de una función) que se ejecute en una fecha y horario determinado:

```
"use strict";

function tarea(){
    console.log('acá va la tarea', new Date());
}

function lanzarElDia(momento, tarea){
    console.log('lanzado',new Date());
    console.log('para ser ejecutado en',momento);
    setTimeout(tarea, momento.getTime()-(new Date()).getTime());
}

lanzarElDia(new Date('2016-06-10 20:29'), tarea);
```

### Ejecutar todos los días a cierta hora

Si en cambio queremos ejecutar una tarea todos los días a las 21:10 debemos calcular cuántos milisengundos faltan para ese momento:

```
"use strict";

function tarea(){
    console.log('acá va la tarea', new Date());
}

function lanzarSiempreALaHora(hora, minutos, tarea){
    var ahora = new Date();
    console.log('lanzado',ahora);
    var momento = new Date(ahora.getFullYear(), ahora.getMonth(), ahora.getDate(), hora, minutos);
    if(momento<=ahora){ // la hora era anterior a la hora actual, debo sumar un día
        momento = new Date(momento.getTime()+1000*60*60*24);
    }
    console.log('para ser ejecutado en',momento);
    setTimeout(function(){
        tarea();
        lanzarSiempreALaHora(hora,minutos,tarea);
    },momento.getTime()-ahora.getTime());
}

lanzarSiempreALaHora(21,10, tarea);
```

### Cuando se cambia la fecha de la máquina

El problema es cuando se cambia la fecha u hora de la máquina. Para ello habría que tener un timer que controle cada minuto (o cada x segundos, de acuerdo a la precisión que se quiera) si ya se llegó a la hora deseada.

### Atención

No hay garantías (con setTimeout ni con ningún cron) que algo se vaya a ejecutar exactamente a un horario, lo único que se sabe es que se va a ejecutar después de la hora señalada y lo antes posible cerca de esa hora.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una tarea programada de Windows que llame a un fichero .bat que contenga la llamada al programa node.

Comment: Gregorio, mira [answer] para mejorar la respuesta. No pongas solo la idea si no  desarrollala explicando como hacer lo que sugieres. Si esto iba con la idea de publicar un comentario, has de esperar a tener 50 de rep para ganar ese privilegio. Si quieres te la puedo convertir a comentario. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias lois6b. Soy nuevo y no conocía la diferencia entre respuesta y comentario. Intentaré mejorar la respuesta.